# How to replenish a data frame based on another one?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given two data frames. One contains a column of repeated values (a, in this case). The other contains what this value corresponds to (in this example, it corresponds to some "d" values). How do I efficiently replenish the first data frame with a new column, values in which correspond to some existent column, according to a rule recorded in the other data frame. Here is an example code that works really slow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([[1,2,3], [2,4,5], [3,4,5], [2,1,4], [3,4,5]]), columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray([[1,7], [2,8], [3,11]]), columns = ['a', 'd'])

d = np.empty((d1.shape[0],))

for i in range(d1.shape[0]):
    temp = d2.loc[d2['a'] == d1.at[i,'a']]
    d[i] = temp['d'].array[0]

d1['d'] = d
```

This is d1 original:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  4  5
2  3  4  5
3  2  1  4
4  3  4  5
```

This is d2:

```
   a   d
0  1   7
1  2   8
2  3  11
```

This is a resultant d1:

```
   a  b  c   d
0  1  2  3   7
1  2  4  5   8
2  3  4  5  11
3  2  1  4   8
4  3  4  5  11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).
In your case, `d1 = d1.merge(d2, on=['a'], how='left')` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `map` and make only the values you need.

```
d1['d'] = d1['a'].map(d2.set_index('a')['d'])
d1
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c   d
0  1  2  3   7
1  2  4  5   8
2  3  4  5  11
3  2  1  4   8
4  3  4  5  11
```